# RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName Returning Wrong Info

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am in South Africa but RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName returns USA, my Application is being hosted by smarterasp.net which i believe their servers are in the USA. But when i run my application local on visual studio it returns current region South Africa, when upload it to server it returns current region USA.

```
using System.Globalization;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string name = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName;
        ViewBag.ip = name;
        return View();
    }
```

}

I am trying to display currency according to country where customer is located

Can any one assist?

Comment: In your `Web.Config`, under `<system.web>` set `<globalization culture="en-ZA" uiCulture="en-ZA" />`

Comment: Thanks so much my brother, it works perfectly.